# Not show picture from word

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor.net

Why images not showing when I paste from MS Word.
Ckeditor show that source

`<h1><img src="file:///C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_image002.jpg" style="height:88px; width:1005px" /></h1>`

This file exist. 
Ckeditor version is for AspNet.
Tested on Chrome, IE 10 and IE 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CKEditor is presumably running on a web page, with a `http://` address.

Modern browsers don't support embedding images (or anything else) from  `file://` URLs in `http://`  pages (or `https://`, or any other protocol) for security reasons.

This is because there'd be the danger of a malicious site embedding something from your private files (like a document), and then using some security hole to read and upload it elsewhere.

But even if this worked, it wouldn't do you much good: the image isn't uploaded into CKEditor so the image would show up on your computer only. Anyone else watching the page you're editing would see a broken image link.

As far as I know, there's currently no way around uploading the image separately.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes i know that this works only on local computer. But i planned convert img to Base64 and change img src, before save in DB.

Comment: I understand. Not possible because of the security restrictions though